# Mask i18n and Theme parameters in URL

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, locale, multi-tenant

I have implemented i18n and theme using Locale and Theme resolver in Spring MVC.

So, all my normal URLs appear like

```
http://localhost/MyApp?lang=en&theme=red
```

Now, if I change the URL manually, the site reflects it immediately.

Is it possible to mask them, so, the User cannot change the language or theme by simply editing the URL?

Comment: What do you mean by 'masking'? You can configure the parameter name to use by settings the `paramName` property of the corresponding `HandlerInterceptor`. More info in [the reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver-interceptor).

Comment: masking i mean, i dnt want the locale and theme parameters to be visible in URL

Comment: I post this question because, I dont know how to do it!

Comment: In a serious note. do you actually understand what am talking??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PRG(POST-Redirect-GET)-pattern. 
You will have to go on your page by POST request. And in your app create controller that will do all business and than redirect user to another address without your request params with GET-request and another controller. No user-changes than will affect your theme or language.